# trouble installing nero AAC on fedora-13

Tags: fedora-13, nero, aac

(i've been asking questions like this a lot lately, eh?)

I'm unable/unsure how to install nero AAC on my fedora-13 box. I've downloaded the zip archive and extracted it. I see a linux directory containing this:

```
neroAacDec  neroAacEnc  neroAacTag
```

no idea what to do next to install this.

i've, alternately, tried "yum search nero", but all I see is:

```
nrg2iso.i686 : Convert Nero Burning Rom image files into ISO
```

which isn't the AAC converter (m4a to mp3) I'm looking for.

Comment: Are they green?

Comment: not green, no. black.

Comment: Open a terminal and do an `ls` of the directory.

Comment: i did, that's what i've posted in the question

Comment: Run `file` against each.

Comment: LSB Executable? output follows:

Comment: linux]$ file nero*
neroAacDec: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
neroAacEnc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
neroAacTag: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

Comment: oh...i'm stupid (from the readme):            Usage:
neroAacEnc [options] -if <input-file> -of <output-file>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have are a bunch of executables that aren't executable. Run `chmod u+x` against them and then put them somewhere convenient such as `~/bin` (which you may need to create first). You will then be able to invoke them using just the command name (and of course, whatever arguments the executable may take).

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to note about the [**Nero encoder**](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nerodigital-nero-aac-codec.php) is that it is a 32bit binary.  If you run it on a 64bit Linux machine and get `No such file or directory` when trying to execute it, like I did here:

```
root@app11:/home/mitayai/nero# chmod 777 ./neroAacEnc
root@app11:/home/mitayai/nero# ./neroAacEnc -if in.wav -of out.aac
bash: ./neroAacEnc: No such file or directory
```

... then try installing the 32bit libraries (these co-exist okay with your 64bit libs)

```
root@app11:/home/mitayai/linux# aptitude install ia32-libs
```

there's a lot of them, but afterwards it may execute fine (as it did for me).

Comment: this download link for the nero encoder/decoder is here: http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nerodigital-nero-aac-codec.php

Answer (score -1):

copy neroAacEnc to /usr/bin and chmod u+x as explained above. this the path cd-rippers (e.g. asunder) will look for codecs, on Fedora 13